# Unable to make a link open in a new tab using _blank

Tags: html, hyperlink

This is the code I am using for my link.

```
<a href="https://dribbble.com/jamesfrewin"><img class="socialicon" src="images/icons/dribbble_dark.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/icons/dribbble_pink.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icons/dribbble_dark.png'" alt="Follow on Dribbble" width="32" height="32"/>
```

I don't seem to be able to get it up open in a new tab I have tried putting

```
target="_blank"
```

everywhere but nothing seems to work?

Comment: What doctype are you using?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MLcB6/ -> it's working here.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `target="_newtab"`:

```
<a target="_newtab" href="https://dribbble.com/jamesfrewin"><img class="socialicon" src="images/icons/dribbble_dark.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/icons/dribbble_pink.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icons/dribbble_dark.png'" alt="Follow on Dribbble" width="32" height="32"/>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help!

I tried that and it sorted it out however it did mess up some of the alignment on my index page?

Could I post it here?

Answer (score 1):

You probably missing something then. This should work just fine (Firefox, Windows at least):

```
<a href="https://dribbble.com/jamesfrewin" target="_blank" id="foo">
  <img class="socialicon" src="images/icons/dribbble_dark.png"
     onmouseover="this.src='images/icons/dribbble_pink.png'"
     onmouseout="this.src='images/icons/dribbble_dark.png'"
     alt="Follow on Dribbble" width="32" height="32"
  />
</a>
```

By the way, you might want to start not to define all your event handlers inline but rather after the page is loaded.

Comment: Oh Really? Thanks - sorry, kinda new to the whole Web Design thing, what do you mean by the event handlers?

Comment: Instead of writing the onmouseover and onmouseout inline you can add then after. With doing so you can have all the dynamic part In one place making it more maintainable. Look up how you can attach event handlers to a given html elent for example with jQuery but even with pure javascript